# loading a whole series of images using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [**this**](http://blog.stableflow.com/jquery-plugins/360-degrees-product-view/) library and what I want to do is to dynamically load the entire series of images in to an element:

```
<div id="product" style="width: 640px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
    /* These images are loaded and appended to the div element dynamically
        <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="images/02.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="images/03.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="images/04.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="images/05.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="images/06.jpg" alt="" />
    /*
</div>
```

and then call the ***j360*** library to set it up:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#product').j360();
});
```

after the images have been loaded.

I have only seen tutorials where one image is loaded like [**this**](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/).... 
Are there any techniques for loading and appending a bunch of images in order?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "load", but you can simply append the `img` element to the parent `div`, and the browser will say, "Hey, there's an image with a `src`, let me go grab it."

**[Here a working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmgonzal/9B6aw/3/)**

Comment: oh! I always thought that the browser ignored the img elements and relied on $.load to download the content... giving it a shot now

Comment: why it never worked for me until now i will never know... =) awesome!

Comment: This solution will not block until all images are fetched. We could call `j360()` when all the images have not been loaded yet.

Comment: True, but that wasn't his question. If you want to wait until all images are loaded, I'd recommend David DeSandro's plugin: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to label the div as loading until ALL of the images to be appended have been properly loaded. This is doable, but a little complicated.

I am assuming you are able to generate an ordered list of image URLs. If this is not the case, then you have some more grunt work to do.

Essentially what we want to do is have each image check off whether or not it has loaded. Once they have all loaded, we can called a done handler and you can replace the loading `.gif` with your product view. Let's do it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="product" style="width: 640px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imageURLs = [ ... ]; // you need to generate this (not too hard)
  var imagesLoaded = 0;
  var images = [ ];

  $.each(imageURLs, function(i, imageURL) {
    var $img = $('<img/>').load(function() {
      imagesLoaded++;
      // See if this was the last image we need to load.
      if (imagesLoaded == imageURLs.length) {
        showProductView();
      }
    })
    .attr('src', imageURL);
    images.push($img);
  });
});

var showProductView = function() {
  var $product = $('#product');
  $.each(images, function(i, $img) {
    $product.append($img);
  });
  $product.removeClass('loading');
  $product.j360();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is specifically what you're looking for in your question, but this plugin will notify you when a set of images are loaded, and allow to perform a callback function after each individual image loads, or the whole set:

http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/

It works great.